# In case of bucket sort, when exactly time complexity is linear? I mean, when distribution is "uniform enough" (looking for math formula on n or k)?

Tags: time-complexity

As in the title. I know that bucket sort is linear when the input is drawn from a uniform distribution. But when is it "uniform enough"? How to describe that in terms of number of buckets (k) and number of elements (n)?

I tried looking for the answer fora long time. Had no success.